# postgresql: prevent superuser from viewing an email column in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, email

I have a ruby on rails app where users can sign up with email addresses. These will be email addresses of real professionals and I cannot be allowed view them for privacy reasons. Let's assume that I cannot have any way to view these email addresses.

I need a way to hide these emails once I use a select query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM users;
```

on the database. 'users' is the table that contains an email column. Once I use this query, I am able to see all of the email addresses of every user, which is problematic.

Here are my attempted solutions:

1) I tried using:

```
update users set email = 'testmail+user'
```

once I entered the psql database, which will set the actual email to a dummy email. The problem is that I have to type this line every single time I want to make an email a dummy email and I can still search for actual emails if I don't type this line.

2) I tried using data-anonymization gem (https://github.com/sunitparekh/data-anonymization), but this relies on a ruby script and I am not so sure how to run this script every time a user signs up.

3) I followed the directions for the tidus gem (https://github.com/Barzahlen/tidus) which supposedly anonymizes content of select columns, but the emails did not change once I entered the psql database and I made my select query.

4) I tried making another user that is not a superuser and REVOKING the SELECT privilege, but then I don't have access to the any other column of the user.

In summary, I need a way to anonymize emails right after they are entered by a user that is signing up OR a way to prevent myself from ever viewing these personal email addresses.

You can assume I still want to view the other columns (i.e., first name, last name).

Comment: This smells suspiciously of homework.  The whole idea of being a database super user is that you can view everything in the database.  If you want to prevent anyone from reading the email address, you need to hash it with a password derivation function like bcrypt, scrypt, or PBKDF2.  However, once hashed, you can only validate that the user entered the correct email address.  You could also encrypt the data before inserting it.  However, the user would have to enter the password to decrypt the record.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, encrypt the value on a computer on which you are not a superuser.

This would mean on an application server, on which you have limited access, or on the users' computers themselves.

There isn't any other way to do it

Why are you recording email addresses if you never want to see/use their real value?